# What a mess [windows] is. Amirite?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently going through [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows) `closed:0 answers:0` and it's a [cesspool](https://serverfault.com/search?page=7&tab=newest&q=%5bwindows%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0).

I'm answering what unloved, but salvageable questions that I can find, but I'm dumping *a lot* of bad questions in [VTC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/161/server-fault-vote-to-close). If you have close votes, but don't normally hang out in VTC, can you ***please*** check on it from time-to-time over the next few days? I get the feeling that there's going to be a lot of junk showing up in there from this query.

Answer (score 5):

Shamelessly adding an answer so we can have this question answered -- ***YES*** [windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows) is a festering stink-pit.

Me personally, I think we should re-tag a lot of these questions into [windows-version](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-version), and continue to answer or nuke the rest.

I will make this tag the focus of my Friday cleaning rage this week and try to isolate any obvious dupes, really bad shopping questions, etc. (and maybe even answer the ones my NT4 MCSE qualifies me for :-)